# Was genau bedeutet "zielwirksam"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

In einigen Büchern über Rhetorik und beim googeln im Kontext von wissenschaftlichem Schreiben findet man öfters das Wort *zielwirksam*.

Es ist weder im Online-Duden noch in Wiktionary gelistet.

## Beispiele

> Zur Frieddialektik gehört ein zweiter Schulungsgegenstand. Hierbei
> geht es darum, durch Argumentation und Kooperation Sachprobleme
> **zielwirksam** zu lösen.
>
> Auf der Sachebene sollte der Moderator in der Lage sein, den Einstieg
> zu optimieren, dafür Sorge zu tragen, dass jeder das jeweilige Problem
> verstanden hat, den Problemlösungsprozess bei jedem Tagesordnungspunkt
> **zielwirksam** und strukturiert zu lenken sowie bei Bedarf unterstützende
> Methoden und Medien einzusetzen.

*Thiele, Albert: Die Kunst zu überzeugen : Faire und unfaire Dialektik. Berlin Heidelberg New York: Springer-Verlag, 2013.*

## Fragen

Was genau bedeutet *zielwirksam*? Ist es synonym zu *effektiv*?

Comment: Es soll wohl effektiv bedeuten, ist aber rar. Wie löst man denn ein Sachproblem, wenn nicht wirksam? Und welche zusätzliche Qualität bringt das Wörtchen ziel ein? Im zweiten Fall würde man eher *zielgerichtet* schreiben. Ohne das Wort *Moderator* würde ich auf einen Fremdwortphobiker tippen. Was ein Wort *genau* bedeutet ist immer so eine Frage - als ob man es sonst nur so grob wissen wollte. Willst Du es genau wissen, musst Du Herrn Thiele selbst fragen, der könnte ja noch leben.

Comment: @userunknown: Das solltest du als Antwort schreiben.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Nun, was es genau bedeutet weiß ich nicht. Was es wahrscheinlich bedeutet hat der Frager selbst erraten. Meine Polemik kann nur der Autor beantworten und ist bei CG auch nicht schlecht aufgehoben. Ich schwanke noch, ob man nicht schließen sollte. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Zunächst zur Bedeutung**

Die Interpretation der Bedeutung von *zielwirksam* ist - speziell mit den Beispielsätzen, die in der Frage angeführt sind - eine knifflige Angelegenheit, denn es gibt Probleme auf mehreren Ebenen. Zunächst mal ist die Frage, was der Autor hier mit *zielwirksam* eigentlich meinte. Dann kommt die Frage, ob er das, was er meinte, mit *zielwirksam* auch gut ausgedrückt hat.

Versuchen wir einmal, herauszufinden, was der Autor gemeint haben könnte.

In den Beispielsätzen aus der Eingangsfrage kann man *zielwirksam* durch *effektiv* ersetzen (wie der Fragesteller ja schon vermutete) und erhält dann allgemeinverständliche Sätze, die auch einen Sinn ergeben.

> Zur Frieddialektik gehört ein zweiter Schulungsgegenstand. Hierbei geht es darum, durch Argumentation und Kooperation Sachprobleme **effektiv** zu lösen.

Warum der Autor nicht einfach *effektiv* gesagt hat, ist mir allerding ein Rätsel. Vielleicht eine Abneigung gegen sogenannte Fremdwörter? Der Autor hätte auch einfach *wirksam* sagen können:

> Zur Frieddialektik gehört ein zweiter Schulungsgegenstand. Hierbei geht es darum, durch Argumentation und Kooperation Sachprobleme **wirksam** zu lösen.

Wobei ich zwischen *wirksam* und *zielwirksam* keinen Unterschied erkennen kann.<sup>1</sup>

Wenn man ganz genau hinschaut, wird es allerdings fraglich, welchen Mehrwert sowohl *zielwirksam* als auch *wirksam* in diesem Satz überhaut haben. Denn wenn davon die Rede ist, Probleme zu lösen, dann ist die Lösung natürlich immer "wirksam", denn wenn sie nicht wirksam ist, ist sie ja keine Lösung.

[Anmerkung: Auch *effektiv* hat möglicherweise dieses Problem. Aber anders als im Gegensatzpaar *wirksame Lösung* vs. *unwirksame Lösung* (wobei die *unwirksame Lösung* dann keine Lösung mehr ist), ergibt *effektive Lösung* vs. *ineffektive Lösung* eher noch einen Sinn, denn man kann *ineffektive Lösung* verstehen als "Lösung, die funktioniert, wenn auch nicht so super gut".]

Also könnte man ohne Verlust auch schreiben:

> Zur Frieddialektik gehört ein zweiter Schulungsgegenstand. Hierbei geht es darum, durch Argumentation und Kooperation Sachprobleme zu lösen.

Was in meinen Augen von allen bisherigen Sätzen der vernünftigste ist.

**Nun zur Polemik:**

Man kann zwar nicht behaupten, dass das Wort

> zielwirksam

nicht existiert (denn hier steht es ja), jedoch kann man über seine Existenzberechtigung füglich einige polemische Worte verlieren.

Für mich gehört *zielwirksam* zum Bürokratenjargon (und vielleicht noch zum Ingenieursjargon), genau wie seine finsteren Brüder

> zielführend

und

> zeitnah

Das sind Wörter, die ich nur aus dem Munde höherer Beamter oder sonstiger administrativer Chefitäten höre, etwa in Fügungen wie *Das ist nicht zielführend* (womit wohl gemeint ist: "Das nützt nichts, das hilft uns nicht weiter") und *Bitte diese E-Mail zeitnah beantworten*, wofür ein normaler Mensch ohne Verschwurbelungssyndrom sagen würde: "Bitte antworten Sie möglichst schnell."

Wie immer man zu diesen Begriffen steht, zur Verwendung in Texten, bei denen es auf guten Stil ankommt, sind sie nicht geeignet. Sie sind sozusagen

> *stilschädlich

**Nachtrag**

Inzwischen ist mir aufgegangen, warum feiner besaitete Geister Wörter wie "zeitnah", "zielführend" und "zielwirksam" als etwas zwischen Beleidigung und Vergewaltigung des Sprachempfindens wahrnehmen.

Direktes Zusammenfügen von Substantiv+Adjektiv (oder Partizip) findet man häufiger, wo zwischen den Elementen einen Akkusativ-Beziehung besteht:

> fleischfressend - wen oder was? Fleisch!
>
> nestbauend - wen oder was? ein Nest!
>
> eierlegend - wen oder was? Eier!
>
> fruchttragend - wen oder was? Frucht!
>
> spaghettikochend - wen oder was? Spaghetti!
>
> erbgutschädigend - wen? das Erbgut!

Für Verhältnisse im Dativ, Genitiv oder Präposition ist diese Wortbildungsart weniger üblich. Man kann sich natürlich darüber hinwegsetzen, aber dann kommen eben so Sachen heraus wie

> zielführend  -  wohin? zum (!) Ziel führend

Dem Sprachempfinden fehlt dann etwas, nämlich der Dativmarker oder die entsprechende Präposition. Das Widerstreben, solche Wendungen zu akzeptieren, sieht man gut, wenn man versucht, das Prinzip produktiv einzusetzen:

> *höllefahrend - zur Hölle fahrend
>
> *bahnhofshaltend - am Bahnhof haltend
>
> *abgrundschauend - wohin? in den Abgrund

Allerdings kann man dem einige Wörter entgegenhalten, die trotz Dativ-Beziehung stilistisch einwandfrei sind:

> hasserfüllt - erfüllt mit Hass
>
> sinnentleert - entleert von Sinn
>
> sonnenzugewandt - wem zugewandt? der Sonne!

Das heißt, offenbar gewöhnt man sich mit der Zeit daran.

---

<sup>1) Man sollte allerdings auch die Möglichkeit in Betracht ziehen, dass in bestimmten fachsprachlichen Kontexten bestimmte Wörter eine besondere Bedeutung haben, die im Alltagssprachgebrauch nicht erkennbar ist. Zum Beispiel kann einem philosophischen Werk ein harmloses Wörtlein wie "Sein" am Anfang in besonderer Weise definiert sein, die man kennen muss, um den Rest des Buches zu verstehen und nicht für trivial zu  halten. Falls dies der Fall sein sollte mit *zielwirksam* in den Beispielsätzen, falls also *zielwirksam* bei Fried eine spezifische Bedeutung haben sollte: sorry!</sup>

Comment: Das ist die beste Analyse die ich hier bisher gelesen habe.